# How to integrate OpenID connect to Nest JS application

Tags: node.js, nestjs, openid-connect, openid, openid-provider

I used this documentation(https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/main/docs/README.md#accounts)for implementing OpenID to Nest JS. In this documentation he mentioned client_id and client secret and redirect URLS. How to get this Information's and Integrating

Answer (score 3):

One option is to create an oidc strategy for `passport`.
It's a lengthy process, and rather than copying/pasting an entire tutorial, I'll add a link and hope it doesn't break.
https://sdoxsee.github.io/blog/2020/02/05/cats-nest-nestjs-mongo-oidc.html

Here's the strategy implementation, but there are several other components that need to be configured.

```
// auth/oidc.strategy.ts
import { UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy, Client, UserinfoResponse, TokenSet, Issuer } from 'openid-client';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

export const buildOpenIdClient = async () => {
  const TrustIssuer = await Issuer.discover(`${process.env.OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_OIDC_ISSUER}/.well-known/openid-configuration`);
  const client = new TrustIssuer.Client({
    client_id: process.env.OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
  });
  return client;
};

export class OidcStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'oidc') {
  client: Client;

  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService, client: Client) {
    super({
      client: client,
      params: {
        redirect_uri: process.env.OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI,
        scope: process.env.OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_LOGIN_SCOPE,
      },
      passReqToCallback: false,
      usePKCE: false,
    });

    this.client = client;
  }

  async validate(tokenset: TokenSet): Promise<any> {
    const userinfo: UserinfoResponse = await this.client.userinfo(tokenset);

    try {
      const id_token = tokenset.id_token
      const access_token = tokenset.access_token
      const refresh_token = tokenset.refresh_token
      const user = {
        id_token,
        access_token,
        refresh_token,
        userinfo,
      }
      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the client-id and secret from the openid connect provider. You add/register the client there.

Redirect URL is the URL to the openid connect client, to what URL the authorization code should be sent to after a successful authentication. This URL is hardcoded in the provider.